# What is this symbol? (MPM notes on conservation of momentum)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, physics

I am trying to read some [MPM notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecffjiang/research/mpmcourse/mpmcourse.pdf). On section 7 there is a formula on the conservation of momentum.
$$ R(X, 0) \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \nabla^X \cdot P + R(X, 0)g $$

There are 2 things I don't get, the left makes sense, it's mass times velocity, i.e. momentum. But the right is nonsensical to me.

First what is $\nabla^X\cdot$ as an operator? That almost looks like it is computing the divergence relative to the material coordinates $X$, but then I don't understand the  equation at all. The left hand side is a vector, the divergence of the pressure is a scalar quantity, so already the types don;t match. And I cannot understand for the life of me what $g$ is supposed to be either.

Comment: Judging by the expression in the 'Eulerian point of view', I think $\nabla^{X}$ is just your standard gradient operator and $\nabla^{X} \cdot$ is just your standard divergence operator. And $P$ isn't the pressure, it's the [Kirchoff stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_stress_measures#Kirchhoff_stress).

Comment: @JohnOmielan no, the left is mass times velocity, that makes sense to show up in a conservation of momentum equation. It;s the right that I don;t get.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you, I am still a little confused. is P then a matrix? I know you said it's a tensor, but the left hand side is a vector and teh only way things will match is if g is a vector and P is a matrix so that it's divergence is a vector.

Comment: I am sorry I am very tired, thank you for cathing that yes, my original statement was confusing, I have edited. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: As it defines a stress, $P$ would be a rank two tensor. You can think of it as a square matrix. The divergence of a rank two tensor yields a rank one tensor, in this case a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Lagrangian equation of motion for deformable continuous media. Heuristically, it can by viewed as an expression of Newton's second law of motion per unit volume. Term by term,

- $R(\boldsymbol{X},0)\, \partial_t \boldsymbol{V}$ is the product between the initial mass density $R(\boldsymbol{X},0)$ in Lagrangian coordinates* and the acceleration $\partial_t \boldsymbol{V}$, where $\boldsymbol{V}$ represents the particle velocity. Thus, this quantity describes inertia per unit volume.
- $\nabla^\boldsymbol{X} \cdot \boldsymbol{P}$ is the Lagrangian divergence of the [first Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_stress_measures) $\boldsymbol{P}$. The latter can be represented as a matrix, so that its divergence is a vector. This term is a cohesion force that is internal to the material.
- $R(\boldsymbol{X},0)\, \boldsymbol{g}$ is the product between the initial mass density and the body forces per unit mass $\boldsymbol{g}$ (e.g., the acceleration of gravity). Therefore it is an external force, see Section 7.2 of the lecture notes.

*Here, the symbol $\boldsymbol{X}$ represents the position of a particle in the initial undeformed state. This space coordinate is commonly used in solid mechanics.

Comment: Is g gravity? Are you sure? Why would the acceleration times the mass density show up in a conservation of momentum equation? Is that not the impulse?

Comment: @Makogan The lecture notes are a bit confusing. In Sec. 7.2, the notation is ${\bf F}^\text{ext} J$ for the body force, a typical example of which is gravity (not to be confused with impulse $\int {\bf f}^\text{ext} \text{d}t$). Thus, we have here ${\bf F}^\text{ext} J = R\, {\bf g}$. The momentum per unit volume reads ${\bf p} = R\, {\bf V}$, and $R\, \partial_t {\bf V}$ is its time derivative. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#In_deformable_bodies_and_fluids) and [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics#Balance_laws)